# Android app does not run on emulator even after the gradle build is finished

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to run my app on emulator, gradle build finishes but the emulator does not run this app. I have tried running other apps they run well on emulator.
So Please help me with this why is this happening?Here is my manifest file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abdus.touristwatch">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Controller.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Controller.selection"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you sure the app isn't crashing? What do you see in Logcat?

Comment: in the logcat info section the message is device state check cancelled

Comment: @breakline in the logcat info section the message is" device state checker cancelled".